# Send Variable from one html to another

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, variables

I have 2 HTML pages, `send.html` and `receive.html`
In each page I have a textield. The thing that I'm trying to do is whenever the "value" of the textfield in the `send.html` changes, automatically parse the data to the textfield value of the `receive.html`. When I say automatically I mean without the need of a button or reloading the pages.

To sum up.. I have this textfiled in the `send.html`

```
<input type="text" id="send" size="25" value="Val1">
```

And this text field in the `receive.html`

```
<input type="text" id="receive" size="25" value="Val2">
```

I want to "monitor" somehow the Val1, and if it changes I want Val2=Val1

For my purpose I cant use jquery.
Is that possible?

Comment: You can or cannot use jQuery?

Comment: "*I have 2 **hmtl** pages*"...???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are missing a **big picture**. Data sending and receiving needs some server side interaction like using PHP, ASP, JSP, Python etc., unless you are ok with `cookies`.

When you update a field in one age, that data needs to go the server somehow for another page to catch. Either way, the way you want it to go automatic is not possible right now. However, I will provide a solution of how you can do this using jQuery and PHP. But if you want?

---

#### Update

So, it seems cookies is the only option. Follow the following steps

Create a new file `cookie.js` and place the following code inside

```
function getCookie(c_name)
{
var i,x,y,ARRcookies=document.cookie.split(";");
for (i=0;i<ARRcookies.length;i++)
  {
  x=ARRcookies[i].substr(0,ARRcookies[i].indexOf("="));
  y=ARRcookies[i].substr(ARRcookies[i].indexOf("=")+1);
  x=x.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,"");
  if (x==c_name)
    {
    return unescape(y);
    }
  }
}

function setCookie(c_name,value,exdays)
{
var exdate=new Date();
exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate() + exdays);
var c_value=escape(value) + ((exdays==null) ? "" : "; expires="+exdate.toUTCString());
document.cookie=c_name + "=" + c_value;
}
```

Next, create two html file "test1.html" and "test2.html" with this markup

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="cookie.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="text" id="text1" name="text1" />
</body>
</html>
```

Now, on test1.html add the following script on the head

```
<script>
    window.onload = function() {
        document.getElementById("text1").onchange = function() {
                                                  // ^ use onkeyup if you want this to occur as you type
            setCookie("shared", this.value, 1);
            alert('oK, val changed so lets check it');              
        };
    };
</script>
```

On Test2.html add the following Script on the head

```
<script>
    var checkandupdate = function() {
           var shared = getCookie("shared");
           if(shared) {

              document.getElementById("text1").value = shared;
           }
    };

    window.onload = function() {
        int = setInterval("checkandupdate()",1000);
    };

</script>
```

#### Now

- Open both pages
- Go to test1.html and type something then press tab to get the alert message.
- Open the test2.html, it should be update within 1 second
- After the demo works, Update the field names as you need

Enjoy ;)

Comment: Thanx Starx, Unfortunately my web server supports these files...HTM, .HTML, .JS, .VBS, .INC, .STM, .XML, .XSL, .HTC,.CSS, .WML, .WMLS,
.XHTML so i cand use PHP

Comment: Thank you very much Starx! Ive downloaded the cookies plugin and tryed with some code,upload it together with the jquery.cookie.js to my server but i wasent able to to do what i want.. =\ I also cant post code back here. Is it posible to post for me the code for send.html and receive.html in order to do what ive described at my first post? Thanx again!!

Comment: @lucky13, Check my update. I create a pure js solution. and its tested. Enjoy ;)

Comment: wow 100000 thanks Starx!! Its working as expected! =D another thing now..is it possible to skip the tab step (i mean the lose focus of the textfield)? So whenever i write something it will be automatically transferred to the page test2 page, even if the cursor is still at the textbox

Comment: @lucky13, use `onkeyup` event for that

Comment: Hey, If my answer worked, please do not forget to accept it as working solution(Click the small tick sign on the left of my answer) or even vote. ;)

Answer (score 0):

In your second HTML page , let's say we call it like `page-2.html?send=xyz` when the value is being changed , you add the following JS Code :

```
function getQueryString() {
  var result = {}, queryString = location.search.substring(1),
      re = /([^&=]+)=([^&]*)/g, m;

  while (m = re.exec(queryString)) {
    result[decodeURIComponent(m[1])] = decodeURIComponent(m[2]);
  }

  return result;
}

var sendValue= getQueryString()["send"];
document.getElementById("receive").value=sendValue;
```

Comment: Yes but i think that in order to have page-2.html?send=xyz i have to write it at the textfield and the submit it, so its not been done automatically. Correct me if im wrong

Comment: Sure , then if the solution is not suitable for you please describe the issue in details in order to help .

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use without cookie for improving the performance.. you can use this [library](http://www.thomasfrank.se/sessionvars.html)  it uses window.name to carry the values..  however it will not work if the user opens in new tab.. still it is good..  only thing is you should handle new tab situation..

Hope this helps.. especially it will help if it is a html based front end..